# Delay between SPI transfers on STM32U5

Tags: stm32, spi

I have to interface an STM32U575 microcontroller with a very specialized SPI device for which the market offers no alternatives. According to the spec sheet, the chip select *must* be pulsed between every 2 bytes, for at least 154 ns. I have to read 34 bytes from this chip every 50 us. The chip allows a maximum SPI clock rate of 24 MHz.

Although I can talk to the device, the SPI controller seems to not be fast enough. I use CubeMX to generate initialization code:

[image: CubeMX SPI configuration]

However, in my attempts to speed these transactions up, I have ditched the HAL for writing/reading to/from the SPI peripheral during the steady state program flow.

SPI functions:

```
void SPIM3_INIT(int len)
{
  SPI3->CFG2 &= ~SPI_CFG2_COMM; // Set Full-Duplex mode
  SPI3->CR2 = len >> 1;         // Set the number of data at current transfer
  SPI3->CR1 |= 1;               // enable
}

int8_t SPIM3_XFER(uint8_t *txb, uint8_t *rxb, int len)
{
  volatile uint16_t *ptxdr_16bits = (volatile uint16_t *)&SPI3->TXDR;
  volatile uint16_t *prxdr_16bits = (volatile uint16_t *)&SPI3->RXDR;
  uint16_t tx_cnt = len >> 1; // divide by 2 for 16 bit xfer
  uint16_t rx_cnt = len >> 1; // divide by 2 for 16 bit xfer

  SPI3->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSTART; // Master transfer start
  while ((tx_cnt > 0UL) || (rx_cnt > 0UL))
  {
    if ((SPI3->SR & SPI_SR_TXP) && (tx_cnt > 0UL))
    {
      *ptxdr_16bits = *(const uint16_t *)txb;
      txb += 2;
      tx_cnt--;
    }
    if ((SPI3->SR & SPI_SR_RXP) && (rx_cnt > 0UL))
    {
      *((uint16_t *)rxb) = *prxdr_16bits;
      rxb += 2;
      rx_cnt--;
    }
  }
  while (!(SPI3->SR & SPI_SR_EOT))
    ;
  SPI3->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_CSTART;
  SPI3->IFCR |= SPI_IFCR_EOTC;  // clear end of transfer flag
  SPI3->IFCR |= SPI_IFCR_TXTFC; // clear transmission xfer filled flag
  return len;
}

void SPIM3_UNINIT()
{
  SPI3->IFCR |= SPI_IFCR_EOTC;                          // clear end of transfer flag
  SPI3->IFCR |= SPI_IFCR_TXTFC;                         // clear transmission xfer filled flag
  SPI3->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;                            // disable peripheral
  SPI3->IER = 0;                                        // disable interrupts
  SPI3->CFG1 &= ~(SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN | SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN); // disable tx dma request
}
```

main:

```
uint8_t tbuf[2] = {0};
uint8_t rbuf[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  tbuf[i] = i;
SPIM3_INIT(2);
while (1)
  SPIM3_XFER(tbuf, rbuf, 2);
SPIM3_UNINIT();
```

The problem is that I am seeing a large period of inactivity between transfers (about 900 ns), as shown in this logic analyzer trace:
[image: Logic Analyzer Trace]

In ideal conditions, I should be able to get the desired throughput with 20 MHz SPI. 2 bytes at 20 MHz take 800 ns to transfer, plus the 154 ns pulse --> 954 ns. Multiply by 34 bytes means I should be able to get this done in about 32 us, meeting my 50 us deadline. Actually, I should be able to get away with up to 670 ns delay between 2-byte transfers (not ideal), but 900ns will certainly not work for me.

Where is this delay coming from? Is it a function of the SPI peripheral architecture? Can my code be optimized further in some way? Can I double buffer the data? Where in the spec sheet can I find reference to these limitations? I am willing to make memory and power trade-offs to increase the bandwidth. Is there some workaround I can use to achieve higher SPI throughput given the limitations of the device I am interfacing with?

Comment: Looks like all 4 MIDI bits in SPI_CFG2 are set.

Comment: @Jens Value of CFG2 is 0x60400000 (MIDI is set to 0)

Comment: @Jens Actually, even when I enable those bits I get the same result. I would have expected it to be longer

Comment: Interesting, this might be a hint, but I have no better idea at the moment. And if you just perform one blind write, wait for RX ready and pick that up without all the status checking?